# ¿Cómo tener el objeto document en un test unitario?

Tags: javascript, dom, test, jestjs

Estoy realizando test unitarios de un código de javascript que corre en el lado del cliente.
El problema lo tengo cuando quiero hacer un test de una función que utiliza el objeto `document`
Aquí va la función en cuestión:

```
function initCanvas(simulationParameters){
    simulationParameters.lienzo = document.getElementById("lienzo");
    simulationParameters.lienzo.setAttribute("width", simulationParameters.wideDimension);
    simulationParameters.lienzo.setAttribute("height", simulationParameters.wideDimension); 
    simulationParameters.ctx = simulationParameters.lienzo.getContext('2d');
    return [simulationParameters.lienzo, simulationParameters.ctx]
}
```

Como se observa en la línea:

```
simulationParameters.lienzo = document.getElementById("lienzo");
```

Se está usando el objeto document.
La pregunta es cómo puedo crear ese objeto (que entiendo que es el propio DOM que se construye en el navegador) sin abrir el navegador. ¿Habrá algún paquete NPM que me de esa utilidad?

Todo esto porque me he montado un motor gráfico con un canvas de html y algo de js.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Usando el paquete jsdom se arregla este problema y también es necesario reescribir la línea:

```
simulationParameters.lienzo = document.getElementById("lienzo");
```

por esta otra:

```
simulationParameters.lienzo = dom.window.document.getElementById("lienzo");
```

Así que finalmente hay que escribir document como una propiedad de window que a su vez es una propiedad de dom.

He instalado también el paquete canvas, pero no estoy seguro de que este paquete sea imprescindible para que pueda hacer mis test unitarios con mi actual código.

A continuación describo con más detalle como utilizar el paquete jsdom:

```
const jsdom = require("jsdom");
const { JSDOM } = jsdom;

const dom = new JSDOM(`<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
<head>
    <meta charset="UTF-8">
    <meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="IE=edge">
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">
    <title>zeroPlayers</title>
    <script type="module" src="./index.js"></script>
</head>
<body>
    <div>
    <canvas id="lienzo">
    </canvas>
    </div>
    <div>
    <button id="playButton">Play Simulation</button>
    <button id="stopButton">Stop Simulation</button>
    </div>
</body>
</html>`);
```